# Структура БД покупки билетов

Tags: mysql, sql, проектирование

Дайте совет в проектировании системы бронирования-покупки билета на автобусы. Моя структура выглядит следующим образом:

- Таблица flight хранится информация о рейсах.
- buses - информация о автобусах и количеством мест в нем.
- tickets - сам билет, в нем есть два внешних ключа на одну таблицу
  stations. stationStart_id - станция отправления пасажира,
  stationEnd_id - станция прибытия пасажира.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Меня интересуют такие моменты:

1. как лучше хранить начальную и конечную станцию в самом
   рейсе(flight). Добавлять туда два внешних ключа на одну таблицу по
   анлогии с таблицей tickets ?
2. Как формировать цены на билет между станциями.
3. Хранения мест автобуса. Добавить возможность выбора номера места,
   при покупке билета.

Comment: А у вас автобусы ездят строго из пункта А в пункт Б, разве не бывает маршрутов включающих более 2х точек ... Хот я я смотрю у вас сейчас в модели то станций больше 2х, тогда зачем что то добавлять в сами рейсы ?

Comment: Продажа билета на некое место некоего рейса от пункта А до пункта В делает невозможным продажу билета на это место этого рейса из пункта А, а также из всех промежуточных между А и В пунктов. В представленной схеме это, вероятно, отдаётся на откуп программной части? не знаю, насколько это надёжно. *Как формировать цены на билет между станциями* Ценовая политика - это не программный вопрос... *Хранения мест автобуса* Они должны быть обязательно! даже если они будут виртуальными, а не реальными - автобус-то не резиновый. Т.е. номер билета должен состоять из индексов конкретного рейса и места.

Comment: 1. Нач (и может быть конечн) хранить в flight. 2. Зависит от вас. а)Либо цена одинаковая б)цена за станцию в)прописать в fligh_has_stations "цену" проезда до следующей/предыдущей (может ссылку на следующую/перыдущую). 3. Место в билет, думаю это логично.

Comment: Автобусы ездят не только с пункта А в Б. Вот и возник вопрос, нужно ли    в таблицу рейсы(fligh) добавить внешний ключ на станцию А (отправления) и станцию Б (конечную). И еще вопрос, два внешних ключа на одну таблицу,хорошо или плохо ?

Answer (score 3):

> 1. Как лучше хранить начальную и конечную станцию в самом рейсе(flight).

Лучше никак не хранить. По-хорошему, у вас должны быть следующие сущности:

- `STATION` - станция (есть). Это справочник точек маршрутов.
- `FLIGHT` - рейс (есть). Это абстрактый рейс как "вещь в себе".
- `FLIGHT_ROUTE` - состав маршрута, то есть список станций, посещаемых автобусом. Он должен содержать `FLIGHT_ID` - ссылку на маршрут, `STATION_ID` - ссылка на станцию, `ARRIVAL_TIME`, `DEPARTURE_TIME` - время прибытия и отправления. Ну можно еще порядковый номер добавить, но это в принципе лишнее. Выбирая первую и последнюю по времени станцию для данного `FLIGHT_ID`, вы получите пункт отправления и назначения.
- `FLIGHT_RUN` - конкретный выезд в рейс. К нему вы будете привязывать билеты, автобусы, плановую и фактическую дату/время отправления.
- Еще нужно добавить `FLIGHT_TICKET` - фактически продаваемые билеты на конкретный рейс и дату. Там будет ссылка на рейс (`FLIGHT_RUN`) и на покупателя (`CLIENT`).
- Еще возможет вариант, когда автобус идет из пункта А в пункт Б, а потом в пункт В. Один пассажир может купить билет от А до Б, а другой - от Б до В.  Их можно посадить на одно место, и даже с замечаниями выше вы это не сделаете. Тут можно добавить пункты "от станции" и "до станции" в таблицу `FLIGHT_TICKET`.

> 2. Как формировать цены на билет между станциями.

Как уже сказали в комментариях, это не задача программирования, это бизнес-задача. Но если это учебный проект и вопрос отдали на ваше усмотрение, можно взять часто используемый вариант разбивания на зоны. Делите станции по зонам, цена билета равна `(некоторая фиксированная сумма) * (N зоны А - N зоны Б)`.

> 3. Хранения мест автобуса. Добавить возможность выбора номера места, при покупке билета.

В принципе, ответил выше. Остается только добавить номер места в таблицу `FLIGHT_TICKET`.

> 4. И еще вопрос, два внешних ключа на одну таблицу, хорошо или плохо?

Не важно. Хорошо - это когда все работает быстро, удобно и без косяков. Плохо - когда наоборот. Сколько вам нужно внешних ключей, чтобы заработало хорошо, столько и делайте.

И еще. У вас часть сущностей названа во множественном числе, а часть - в единственном. Выработайте какой-то один стиль и работайте в нем - проще будет запоминать.

Comment: FLIGHT_TICKET - по сути это таблица tickets у меня будет ?

Comment: @SerhiyLytvyn Хм, пожалуй, да. Как-то я ее упустил из виду.

Comment: Возник еще один вопрос, как хранить расписание маршрута. К примеру есть автобусы которые ходят только по выходным или ПН-ПТ. Мой вариант такой: сделать таблицу типы рейса и хранить там(ежедневный, ПН, ВТ, СБ и тд...) и добавить type_id во flight. Но как как контролировать сам маршрут ? не могу придумать.